# Malloc - Why does this string accept this text with a smaller allocation?

Tags: c

I would like to know why this program does not segfault ?

```
    int main(void)
    {
          char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);

          s = "Hello world !";
          printf("%s\n", s);
    }
```

I mean I've allocated only 5 char of size but it prints the entire text.

Thanks.

Comment: `"Hello world !"` is a string literal which is allocating its own memory and you now have no way of freeing the memory you malloced.

Comment: and you are leaking memory.

Comment: What you do is equivalent to `int s = 5; s = 10;`. The assignment makes you lose the original value of `s`.

Answer (score 5):

After

```
char* s = malloc(5);
```

s is *pointing* to the allocated memory

with

```
s = "Hello World !";
```

you set s to *point* to another place in memory, you are not copying the string to where s is pointing. For that you need to use strcpy or memcpy.

Answer (score 4):

Because *you didn't do anything that would cause it to*.

You have *memory leak*. That's it. You are assigning the address of the string literal.(string literal being an array decays into pointer to the first element of it). And losing the old allocated chunks address.

If you did `strcpy(s,"hello world!");` then yes it would likely to have a segfault. For sure then your program would have undefined behaviour.

Also, note one thing `s = "hello world";` do not copies string literal `"hello world"` to `s`. That is not the case. Simply you have the address of the string literal and then you pass it to `printf` and `%s` format specifier outputs character until it gets `\0` and it gets one. (Because string literals are null terminated).

For your information,

> A segmentation fault (aka segfault) is a common condition that causes
>   programs to crash; they are often associated with a file named core.
>   Segfaults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal
>   memory location.

Here you didn't do anything like that.

---

<sup>Remember one thing whenever you allocate dynamically allocated memory - free it after you are done working with. For this refer to this function `free()`. Also, it is good to check the return value of `malloc`. The thing is when you are pointing to the string literal via `s` then if you try to modify it you will likely to get segmentation fault also. Because string literals are non-modifiable.</sup>

In summary, the code doesn't use the allocated memory after you allocate. And that memory is leaked. And then you assign the pointer to string literal to `s` and then it printed what is expected to. The code has no undefined behaviour issue.

Answer (score 1):

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

You violate rule (1) which forecloses being able to satisfy rule (2).

One way to be able to visualize what you are doing is either to use a debugger, or simply look at the addresses for `s` after `malloc` and then again after your assignment of `"Hello world !"` (note: you should also validate that your call to `malloc` succeeds before further use of `s`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    if (!s) {
        perror ("malloc - s");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("1. address of s : %p\n", s);

    s = "Hello world !";

    printf ("2. address of s : %p\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/saddress
1. address of s : 0xa45010
2. address of s : 0x4006f5
```

The addresses have changed? Why? What variable remains holding the original address for the `malloc`ed `s`? How will you ever `free` the memory you allocated?

As explained in a number of the answers and comments `"Hello world !"` is a *string literal* created in **read-only** memory whose address is the address of the first character `'H'`. You also requested and assigned the address of a newly allocated block of memory to `s` when you called `malloc`. Unless you preserve the original address contained in `s` after your call to `malloc`, you cannot `free` the memory you allocated -- resulting in a *memory leak*. Essentially, you lost the address to the allocated block of memory when you assigned `s = "Hello world !";` (because `s` now holds the address to the beginning of `"Hello world !"`)

If it is still fuzzy, let's look at another example that does exactly the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *literal = "Hello world !";
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    if (!s) { 
        perror ("malloc - s"); 
        return 1; 
    }

    printf ("1. address of s : %p\n", s);

    s = literal;

    printf ("2. address of s : %p\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the exact same problems occur. You allocate for `s`, then assign the address of `"Hello world !"` (held by the pointer `literal`) to `s` losing your reference to the original block of memory.

The issue would have become painfully clear had you tried to `free (s);`.

How do you fix the problem? (don't overwrite `s` to begin with) But, since you are free to overwrite `s`, how do you insure you do not lose you reference to the block of memory allocated with `malloc`? It's quite simple, just preserve the address with another pointer, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *literal = "Hello world !";
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    char *p = s;
    if (!s) { 
        perror ("malloc - s"); 
        return 1; 
    }

    printf ("1. address of s : %p\n", s);

    s = literal;

    printf ("2. address of s : %p\n", s);

    printf ("3. address of p : %p\n", p);

    free (p);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/saddress3
1. address of s : 0x1a96010
2. address of s : 0x400745
3. address of p : 0x1a96010
```

You can check with `valgrind` (or similar memory error checker), that all memory has been freed and there are no memory error.

If you still have questions, just ask. All here are happy to help.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped. Remember, a pointer is just a variable that holds the address to something else as its value. Since you use the variable `s` to hold the address returned by `malloc`, you must preserve the contents of `s` (or at least a reference to the address held by `s`) so that you can `free` the memory block beginning at that address when it is no longer needed. Good luck with your coding.